# Way to make Emacs' M-x rgrep work with both UTF8 and UTF16 files?

Tags: utf-8, emacs, utf-16

Is it possible to customize Emacs so that `rgrep` would correctly find occurrences of some pattern in both UTF8 (or even Latin) and UTF16 files?

I guess we should customize `grep-find-template`, but can't make my way through it.

**EDIT 2017-06-16**
I do now have an example of working *utf-8/16* `cat` command for the shell. It should then be transformed for the Emacs's `grep`, if that's possible. Here it is:

```
cat $1 | ( [[ $(file -i $1) =~ utf-16be ]] && ( iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 || true ) || cat )
```

Comment: Which `grep` options do you need to use for that?

Comment: Currently, `grep-find-template` is equal to `"find <D> <X> -type f <F> -print0 | \"xargs\" -0 grep <C> -nH -e <R>"`.

Comment: What I do need (let's say would like) is that `grep` works for all file types I do have, that is ISO Latin 1, UTF-8 and now UTF-16.

Comment: FYI, I'm using Cygwin Emacs, but I do have `iconv` utility as well with Cygwin.

Comment: It sounds like the first thing you need is an executable which analyses the encoding of its file argument, and calls `iconv` with appropriate arguments to output the file in your desired encoding for `grep` purposes?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a programming question - it may find better answers over on [emacs.se].